# Why is T-SQL converting my DECIMAL data to INT?

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, casting

I have a table with a column defined as follows:

```
PrincipalBalance DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL
```

I have a stored procedure that returns that value as follows:

```
SELECT D.PrincipalBalance
  FROM MyTable AS D
 WHERE ID = @myKey;
```

If I inspect the metadata for the table, the column definition is correct (it shows as `DECIMAL(13,2)`.) It shows with the correct type in Object Explorer as well. However, IntelliSense for the column in the stored procedure shows that it is an `INT`, which is thoroughly puzzling.

The only workaround I have found for this is to use a `CAST`/`CONVERT` in the stored procedure, which seems like it should be unnecessary.

**Note** Earlier today I experienced the same problem with a decimal column that the was being returned as a `VARCHAR(50)` (or some other relevant length). It's interesting that in both cases, the value of the decimal column was zero.

What is going on here? Why is SQL Server selecting the wrong type?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Is it *only* that Intellisense is showing the column as an INT? Part of my confusion is that I don't understand what you are accomplishing when you convert the value in a stored proc.

Intellisense can be flaky. I frequently need to refresh the local cache (CTRL+SHIFT+R) which usually helps (but not always.) I have the same issue when I change a table and don't refresh the cache -- intellisense shows the object's previous state. I don't know, however, if this is the problem you're running into

Comment: What steps can we take to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Did that column change datatypes recently and somehow the SQL Server metadata has not been updated?

Comment: Run this query...

SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your schema'
       AND TABLE_NAME = 'your table';

What datatype is your problematic column?

Comment: @AlanBurstein Apologies for the late responses. The issue is that, from Entity Framework's perspective, the data is being materialized as an `int`, which is what is coming back from the stored procedure. However, in the source table, it is a `decimal(13,2)`, and the target model in C# has it defined as a C# `decimal`. Consequently, a mapping failure occurs. The only workaround I've been able to find is to perform the `CONVERT` back to the type defined in the table schema in the stored procedure.

Comment: @Isaac No, the table schema has not changed. We were previously consuming the data using a different technique; only when Entity Framework entered the picture did we become aware of the issue. Also, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` shows the data type for the column as `DECIMAL(13,2)`.